# UIPasteBoard Changes my Image Orientation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uipasteboard

I am Copying the array of Images in `UIPasteBoard` and When I try to Paste the images in `mail` the Image orientation is changing. This is How I am Copying the Images.

```
UIPasteboard *pasteBoard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
pasteBoard.images = imageArray;
```

How can I copy the images without changing the Image orientation ?

Answer (score 0):

UIImage's imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation: method can modify the orientation if you're not pleased with the results.

What your mail app is displaying is probably the true pixel array before the orientation info is applied to rotate it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIImage/imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:

Comment: But it is not possible for me to change the default paste option in the mail app..

Comment: You shouldn't need to change the pasting at all.  Simply look at the dimensions of the image and negotiate the orientation to match.

Answer (score 0):

I have this working. I just use the setData to give it raw data and then set the data type using forPasteboardType. Right below your

if (fileExists){

Try this

```
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:imagefile];
    [pasteboard setData:data forPasteboardType:@"public.png"];
```

May this Helping to you.

Comment: but with this I can able to copy only one image. I want to copy multiple images..